# Set a scrollable background image

Tags: html, css

I currently have this fiddle :  
https://jsfiddle.net/0g3u8452/1/ 
I have a 1920x4000 image, and I would like it to take the full width of the screen just like the

```
background-size: cover
```

but since the image has an important height, I'd like to be able to scroll down to keep seeing it

I made a picture of the result i'm trying to get :

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Comment: Hi @GopalGarva, with this property, I'm not able to scroll at the bottom of my picture :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `<img>` with `position: absolute` as a background instead?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container img.background-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x4000" class="background-img">
  <div class="other">Other elements</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/78nwu0k9/)

```
.bg {
 height: 4000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Psky/0g3u8452/20/)?  i just changed it a bit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="bg">
      <div class="cont"></div>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>


body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4000px;
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/1920x4000");
}
```